# Training Error in PyTorch - RuntimeError: Expected object of type FloatTensor vs ByteTensor

Tags: python, image, pytorch, tensor, conv-neural-network

A minimal working sample will be difficult to post here but basically I am trying to modify this project http://torch.ch/blog/2015/09/21/rmva.html which works smoothly with MNIST. I am trying to run it with my own dataset with a custom `dataloader.py` as below:

```
from __future__ import print_function, division #ds
import numpy as np
from utils import plot_images

import os #ds
import pandas as pd #ds
from skimage import io, transform #ds
import torch
from torchvision import datasets
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader #ds
from torchvision import transforms
from torchvision import utils #ds
from torch.utils.data.sampler import SubsetRandomSampler


class CDataset(Dataset):


    def __init__(self, csv_file, root_dir, transform=None):
        """
        Args:
            csv_file (string): Path to the csv file with annotations.
            root_dir (string): Directory with all the images.
            transform (callable, optional): Optional transform to be applied
                on a sample.
        """
        self.frame = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.frame)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img_name = os.path.join(self.root_dir,
                                self.frame.iloc[idx, 0]+'.jpg')
        image = io.imread(img_name)
#       image = image.transpose((2, 0, 1))
        labels = np.array(self.frame.iloc[idx, 1])#.as_matrix() #ds
        #landmarks = landmarks.astype('float').reshape(-1, 2)
        #print(image.shape)
        #print(img_name,labels)
        sample = {'image': image, 'labels': labels}

        if self.transform:
            sample = self.transform(sample)

        return sample

class ToTensor(object):
    """Convert ndarrays in sample to Tensors."""


    def __call__(self, sample):
        image, labels = sample['image'], sample['labels']
        #print(image)
        #print(labels)
        # swap color axis because
        # numpy image: H x W x C
        # torch image: C X H X W
        image = image.transpose((2, 0, 1))
        #print(image.shape)
        #print((torch.from_numpy(image)))
        #print((torch.from_numpy(labels)))
        return {'image': torch.from_numpy(image),
                'labels': torch.from_numpy(labels)}


def get_train_valid_loader(data_dir,
                           batch_size,
                           random_seed,
                           #valid_size=0.1, #ds
                           #shuffle=True,
                           show_sample=False,
                           num_workers=4,
                           pin_memory=False):
    """
    Utility function for loading and returning train and valid
    multi-process iterators over the MNIST dataset. A sample
    9x9 grid of the images can be optionally displayed.

    If using CUDA, num_workers should be set to 1 and pin_memory to True.

    Args
    ----
    - data_dir: path directory to the dataset.
    - batch_size: how many samples per batch to load.
    - random_seed: fix seed for reproducibility.
    - #ds valid_size: percentage split of the training set used for
      the validation set. Should be a float in the range [0, 1].
      In the paper, this number is set to 0.1.
    - shuffle: whether to shuffle the train/validation indices.
    - show_sample: plot 9x9 sample grid of the dataset.
    - num_workers: number of subprocesses to use when loading the dataset.
    - pin_memory: whether to copy tensors into CUDA pinned memory. Set it to
      True if using GPU.

    Returns
    -------
    - train_loader: training set iterator.
    - valid_loader: validation set iterator.
    """
    #ds
    #error_msg = "[!] valid_size should be in the range [0, 1]."
    #assert ((valid_size >= 0) and (valid_size <= 1)), error_msg
    #ds

    # define transforms
    #normalize = transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))
    trans = transforms.Compose([
        ToTensor(), #normalize,
    ])

    # load train dataset
    #train_dataset = datasets.MNIST(
    #    data_dir, train=True, download=True, transform=trans
    #)


    train_dataset = CDataset(csv_file='/home/Desktop/6June17/util/train.csv',
                                    root_dir='/home/caffe/data/images/',transform=trans)

    # load validation dataset
    #valid_dataset = datasets.MNIST( #ds
    #    data_dir, train=True, download=True, transform=trans #ds
    #)

    valid_dataset = CDataset(csv_file='/home/Desktop/6June17/util/eval.csv',
                                    root_dir='/home/caffe/data/images/',transform=trans)

    num_train = len(train_dataset) 
    train_indices = list(range(num_train)) 
    #ds split = int(np.floor(valid_size * num_train))

    num_valid = len(valid_dataset) #ds
    valid_indices = list(range(num_valid)) #ds

    #if shuffle:
    #    np.random.seed(random_seed)
    #    np.random.shuffle(indices)

    #ds train_idx, valid_idx = indices[split:], indices[:split]
    train_idx = train_indices #ds
    valid_idx = valid_indices #ds

    train_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(train_idx)
    valid_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(valid_idx)

    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, sampler=train_sampler,
        num_workers=num_workers, pin_memory=pin_memory,
    )

    print(train_loader)

    valid_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        valid_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, sampler=valid_sampler,
        num_workers=num_workers, pin_memory=pin_memory,
    )

    # visualize some images
    if show_sample:
        sample_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
            dataset, batch_size=9, #shuffle=shuffle,
            num_workers=num_workers, pin_memory=pin_memory
        )
        data_iter = iter(sample_loader)
        images, labels = data_iter.next()
        X = images.numpy()
        X = np.transpose(X, [0, 2, 3, 1])
        plot_images(X, labels)

    return (train_loader, valid_loader)


def get_test_loader(data_dir,
                    batch_size,
                    num_workers=4,
                    pin_memory=False):
    """
    Utility function for loading and returning a multi-process
    test iterator over the MNIST dataset.

    If using CUDA, num_workers should be set to 1 and pin_memory to True.

    Args
    ----
    - data_dir: path directory to the dataset.
    - batch_size: how many samples per batch to load.
    - num_workers: number of subprocesses to use when loading the dataset.
    - pin_memory: whether to copy tensors into CUDA pinned memory. Set it to
      True if using GPU.

    Returns
    -------
    - data_loader: test set iterator.
    """
    # define transforms
    #normalize = transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))
    trans = transforms.Compose([
        ToTensor(), #normalize,
    ])

    # load dataset
    #dataset = datasets.MNIST(
    #    data_dir, train=False, download=True, transform=trans
    #)

    test_dataset = CDataset(csv_file='/home/Desktop/6June17/util/test.csv',
                                    root_dir='/home/caffe/data/images/',transform=trans)

    test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False,
        num_workers=num_workers, pin_memory=pin_memory,
    )

    return test_loader


#for i_batch, sample_batched in enumerate(dataloader):
#    print(i_batch, sample_batched['image'].size(),
#          sample_batched['landmarks'].size())

#    # observe 4th batch and stop.
#    if i_batch == 3:
#        plt.figure()
#        show_landmarks_batch(sample_batched)
#        plt.axis('off')
#        plt.ioff()
#        plt.show()
#        break
```

Other main change I have made is closing off the parameter intake for validation size and shuffling (as I am using a pre-existing train, validation and test split and I have already shuffled these splits)

And my last change is in `train_one_epoch(self, epoch)` function, while iterating in `trainer.py`. I have changed this part because formerly the `x`, `y` were being returned as strings of `"image"` and `"labels"` - headers of the python dictionary rather than the values in batches.

```
for i, batch in enumerate(self.train_loader):
     x, y = batch["image"], batch["labels"]
```

But now I get errors with the network training that I can not figure out as I am new to pytorch:

```
[*] Train on 64034 samples, validate on 18951 samples Epoch: 1/200 - LR: 0.000300 <torch.utils.data.dataloader.DataLoader object at 0x7fe065fd4f60>   0%|                                                  | 0/64034 [00:00<?, ?it/s]/home/duygu/recurrent-visual-attention-master/modules.py:106: UserWarning: invalid index of a 0-dim tensor. This will be an error in PyTorch 0.5. Use tensor.item() to convert a 0-dim tensor to a Python number   from_x, to_x = from_x.data[0], to_x.data[0] /home/duygu/recurrent-visual-attention-master/modules.py:107: UserWarning: invalid index of a 0-dim tensor. This will be an error in PyTorch 0.5. Use tensor.item() to convert a 0-dim tensor to a Python number   from_y, to_y = from_y.data[0], to_y.data[0]

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 49, in <module>
    main(config)   File "main.py", line 40, in main
    trainer.train()   File "/home/duygu/recurrent-visual-attention-master/trainer.py", line 168, in train
    train_loss, train_acc = self.train_one_epoch(epoch)   File "/home/duygu/recurrent-visual-attention-master/trainer.py", line 252, in train_one_epoch
    h_t, l_t, b_t, p = self.model(x, l_t, h_t)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 491, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)   File "/home/duygu/recurrent-visual-attention-master/model.py", line 101, in forward
    g_t = self.sensor(x, l_t_prev)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 491, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)   File "/home/duygu/recurrent-visual-attention-master/modules.py", line 214, in forward
    phi_out = F.relu(self.fc1(phi))   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 491, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py", line 55, in forward
    return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 992, in linear
    return torch.addmm(bias, input, weight.t()) RuntimeError: Expected object of type torch.FloatTensor but found type torch.ByteTensor for argument #4 'mat1'
```

I am seeking recommendations on how to fix this error and to understand what is causing it.I get this error even when I run it without GPU support on. I wonder if somehow my parameters are passed empty by looking at the initial warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it seems that as you commented the `normalize` / `transforms.Normalize` operations applied to your dataset, your images don't have their values normalize to `float` between `[0, 1]`, and are instead keeping their `byte` values between `[0, 255]`.

Try applying data normalization or at least converting your images to `float` (32-bit, not 64) values (e.g. in `ToTensor`, add `image = image.float()` or while it is still a numpy array using `data.astype(numpy.float32)`) before feeding them to your network.

Comment: Hey, thank you for noticing that. Really helpful! I prefer not to normalize due to the nature of my data (or at least not subtract the mean). In ToTensor (or right after I read the image) I cast the type with image = image.astype(float) -since it is a numpy array- but this time I get  RuntimeError: Expected object of type torch.FloatTensor but found type torch.DoubleTensor for argument #4 'mat1' I am trying to see why

Comment: I don't know how your tensor `mat1` is defined / what data it is assigned, but you could try either to redefine `mat1` as a `torch.DoubleTensor` or to cast the data e.g. to `numpy.float32` before assigning.

Comment: Alright thanks, the awkward thing is it is the same mat1 I received the former error (then it claimed it received byte and now it claims it is double even after I cast it to float)

Comment: I may be wrong, but I believe if your machine is 64-bit, python `float` will be 64-bit too, i.e. what we call `double`. Hence the suggestion to explicitly cast your data to `numpy.float32` instead of generic `float`.

Comment: Thanks, I have actually tried that as well but got a mismatch RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [32 x 192], m2: [64 x 128] at /pytorch/aten/src/TH/generic/THTensorMath.c:2033 And explicitly casting to Float64 gets me back to the prev error. The mat1 should be a weight in the model so I am not exactly sure why casting the input image to float is not fixing the problem

Comment: do I need to cast all input to float? That sounds awkward for labels though but not sure about pytorch limitations, I will try to check

Comment: Using the proper type (`np.float32`) worked, but your code crashed for another error appearing right after. It seems that (despite the correct types), you are trying to do some operations between 2 tensors of different shapes (`mat1` of shape `32 x 192` and `mat2` of shape `64 x 128`). This is not related to type/casting anymore. I would suggest you check your network architecture, and open a new question for this different issue if needed.

Comment: Alright, I will check it out. The network works smoothly with MNIST (I just import it from pytorch framework), so I am pretty sure it is my dataloader but I am not seeing it.

Comment: It is possible the error is caused by using inputs of a different size than the MNIST ones, or something related... Good luck finding out!